# Hartls Chapter 11: undefined method `following_user_path'

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get through the last and final chapter of the Hartl tutorial, but keep getting the below error for multiple tests across all specs. The tests started to fail as soon as I entered in the following/followers behavior into my code.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `following_user_path'
```

Here's an example of a spec that is failing:

```
describe "visiting the following page" do
    before { visit following_user_path(user) }
    it { should have_in_title('Sign in') }
end
```

Here's the extracted source from _stats.html.erb (line #3):

```
<% @user ||= current_user %>
<div class="stats">
    <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
        <strong id="following" class="stat">
            <%= @user.followed_users.count %>
        </strong>
        following
    </a>
    <a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
        <strong id="followers" class="stat">
            <%= @user.followers.count %>
        </strong>
        followers
    </a>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :sessions,      only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts,    only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, 
                only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    if signed_in?
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Already signed in."
    else
      @user = User.new
    end  
  end

  def create
    if signed_in?
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Already signed in."
    else
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
      if @user.save
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    if (current_user == user) && current_user.admin?
      flash[:error] = "Cannot delete own admin account."
    else
      user.destroy
      flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    end
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  def feed
    microposts
    #Micropost.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end

  def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)
  end

  def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id).destroy
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

rake routes

```
following_user GET    /users/:id/following(.:format) users#following
followers_user GET    /users/:id/followers(.:format) users#followers
         users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
               POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
      new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
     edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
          user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
      sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)            sessions#create
   new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)        sessions#new
       session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)        sessions#destroy
    microposts POST   /microposts(.:format)          microposts#create
     micropost DELETE /microposts/:id(.:format)      microposts#destroy
 relationships POST   /relationships(.:format)       relationships#create
  relationship DELETE /relationships/:id(.:format)   relationships#destroy
          root        /                              static_pages#home
        signup        /signup(.:format)              users#new
        signin        /signin(.:format)              sessions#new
       signout DELETE /signout(.:format)             sessions#destroy
          help        /help(.:format)                static_pages#help
         about        /about(.:format)               static_pages#about
       contact        /contact(.:format)             static_pages#contact
```

spec_helper.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
end

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

Also, this is my first time posting here, so excuse me if I'm not posting things correctly.  And please let me know if there's any other useful information I should include.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you produce the results of `rake routes` when you type that into the terminal?

Comment: Just added -- thanks, jason328!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately one cannot just call route methods in tests. You can add it though. Check to see if you have this code below in your `spec_helper.rb` file.

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
  # The line below should be in the file, if not add it.
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

EDIT: Your `spec_helper.rb` file should look like this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
    config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
end
```

EDIT AGAIN: Spork is a nifty little tool used for running tests. Long story short if you have a lot of tests, it takes awhile. Spork helps ease that by making the tests quicker. Once you get more familiar with testing I suggest you take a look at it.

Comment: Didn't see that in my spec_helper.rb file (should there be a separate rspec_helper.rb file?). After adding it in, still got the same errors. Posted spec_helper.rb above

Comment: Are you using spork in your tests? Sorry I meant `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: This is where my newb-ness is going to make things tough. I included spork based on early recos in the Hartl tutorial. I'm not actually sure how to use it (or what it does for that matter) :-/

Comment: Updated my answer. I'm as well a bit noobish with `spec_helper.rb` files so lets up this works.

Comment: Nice! That cleared most of the errors. Now I'm getting just this one:     NoMethodError:
           undefined method `follower_user_path'

Comment: Oh wait! Got it to work. Just needed to change 'follower' to 'followers'. Coding can be so nit-picky! Thanks for your help, Jason.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! You can either add your own answer of what you did or accept mine. Just remember to mark whichever answer as correct.